# Sonar issue: "Overide the "equals" method in this class

Tags: java, inheritance, sonarqube, equals

I was cleaning the code of the system on which I work, cleaning some Sonar tool issues, and I came across the following message:

> Overide the 'equals' method in this class

I did some research but nothing that answered the "why" of this note

We are using a parent class with `EqualsBuilder` which provides
`EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals`, so the correction is just to declare the method overwritten by passing the `equals` method of the parent class

```
     @Override
     public boolean equals (Object o) {
         return super.equals (o);
     }
```

by guarantee I'm also overwriting the hashCode method, but in the same way passing the responsibility to the parent class (same case for reflectionHashCode `HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode`)

```
     @Override
     public int hashCode () {
         return super.hashCode ();
     }
```

But still my question remains, why do I have to override this method if it can be achieved in inheritance?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's not much point overriding `equals` and `hashCode` just to return the superclass's implementation. Whether your class _ought_ to override those methods depends on what your class does and how it is supposed to work. It's possible the recommendation is simply inappropriate in your case.

Comment: Does the subclass have any additional properties? If so that might be the reason Sonar suspects an error here.

Comment: @Thomas no, there is nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple hack, since the `super` Class has `@Override` the `equals` and `hashCode`.

add it to class (if you are already using `Lombok`):

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
```

unless the subclass class has its own `equals` and `hashCode`.